# How can i reset my input field after submitting the form in ReactJS?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, forms

I tried setting the state to an empty string but it's not working, the entered value is resetted but it's still showing the entered value inside the input field. How can i fix this?

```
import { useState } from 'react';

const App = () => {
const [task,setTask] = useState('');
const [list,setList] = useState([]);


const submitHandler = (event) => {
  event.preventDefault();
  const newTask = { id: new Date().getTime().toString(), title: task };
  setList([...list, newTask]);
  setTask('');
}

const clearList = () => {
  setList([]);
}

const removeItem = (id) => {
    const filteredList = list.filter(item => item.id !== id);
    setList(filteredList);
}

  return <div>
          <h2>To do list!</h2>
          <form onSubmit={submitHandler}> Enter Task! 
          <input type='text'
            placeholder='Wut you upto?'
            onChange = {(event) => {setTask(event.target.value)}}>
          </input>
          </form>
          <div>
          {list.map((obj) => (
          <h4 key={obj.id}>{obj.title}<button onClick={() => removeItem(obj.id)}>X</button></h4>))}
          <button onClick={clearList}>Clear All</button>
          </div>
          </div>
}

export default App
```

Answer (score 3):

you need to add `value` attribute to the input field:

```
          <input type='text'
            placeholder='Wut you upto?'
            onChange = {(event) => {setTask(event.target.value)}}>
            value={task}
          </input>
```